# With mongoosastic, not_analyzed parameter is not applied when indexing fields into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am indexing a mongoose model into Elasticsearch using [mongoosastic](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic) and by specifying the fields using `es_indexed: true`, which worked fine.

Now I want some of those fields not to be analyzed by using the `index: 'not_analyzed'` option, but it doesn't work.

I ran `GET /actions/_mapping` in Elasticsearch to check the mapping, and the option is not shown. Therefore I guess that mongoosastic is not passing it.

I also tried to delete the index from Elasticsearch to ensure that it takes my edits into consideration, but it didn't change neither.

If I manually enter the index using `PUT /actions`, then it works, but the goal is to have it in the schema declaration, as below.

```
var actionSchema = exports.Schema = mongoose.Schema({
  published: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    es_indexed: true
  },
  actorUser: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    es_indexed: true
  },
  actor: {
    type: activityObject,
    es_indexed: true
  },
  pictureUrl: String,
  verb: {
    type: String,
    es_indexed: true,
    index: 'not_analyzed'
  },
  object: {
    type: activityObject,
    es_indexed: true
  },
  target: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      es_indexed: true
    },
    displayName: {
      type: String,
      es_indexed: true,
      index: 'not_analyzed'
    },
    objectType: {
      type: String,
      es_indexed: true
    },
    image: String,
    url: String
  },
  path: {
    type: String,
    es_indexed: true
  },
  recipients: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
});
```

Any idea what I should do to make it work?

[EDIT] I asked the question on mongoosastic GitHub repository where the problem is currently flagged as a possible bug: https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/issues/76

Comment: naah both es_index: 'not_analyzed' and es_indexed:'not_analyzed' not working also in mongoosastic where to speccify type name coz it by default take type name from index name ??

Answer (score 0):

In mongoosastic es_ should be prefix in schema.

Try with  ->

```
es_index: "not_analyzed"
```